# MySQL Multiple Counts within Date Groups

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT calldate, from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(calldate)/(60*60))*(60*60)) GroupTime
 , COUNT(*) as CntOut FROM asterisk.cdr 
 WHERE accountcode = '10102-131' AND DATE (calldate) = DATE (NOW()) AND calltype = 'outgoing' 
 GROUP BY GroupTime;
```

I have this query which groups a count for every hour of date for *outgoing* calls. Is there any way to get also the count of *incoming* as well in the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 Calldate
 from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(calldate)/(60*60))*(60*60)) GroupTime, 
 SUM(calltype='incoming') as CntIn, 
 SUM(calltype='outgoing') as CntOut 
FROM asterisk.cdr 
WHERE accountcode = '10102-131' 
  AND DATE (calldate) = DATE (NOW()) 
  AND calltype IN ('incoming', 'outgoing' )
GROUP BY GroupTime;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23546/3)

Comment: I'm getting similar results on all solutions only each row is not grouping.

2015-07-05 11:50:00 2015-07-05 11:00:00 0 1
2015-07-05 11:56:52 2015-07-05 11:00:00 0 1
2015-07-05 12:15:00 2015-07-05 12:00:00 0 1
2015-07-05 12:15:15 2015-07-05 12:00:00 0 1
2015-07-05 12:15:27 2015-07-05 12:00:00 0 1
2015-07-05 12:15:58 2015-07-05 12:00:00 0 1
2015-07-05 12:17:09 2015-07-05 12:00:00 0 1
2015-07-05 12:20:05 2015-07-05 12:00:00 0 1

Comment: @AD001 I've updated the query and Fiddle. Try removing the Calldate from the group by.

Comment: @AD001 There is some good additional information and tips in the answer by Gordon Linoff too that I didn't incorporate into this, but you should look at that too :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "outgoing" and "incoming" are descriptors on the call:

```
SELECT date(calldate), hour(calldate) as callhour,
       count(*) as Cnt,
       sum(calltype = 'outgoing') as CntOut,
       sum(calltype = 'incoming') as CntIn
FROM asterisk.cdr 
WHERE accountcode = '10102-131' AND
      (calldate >= curdate() and calldate < date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
      ) AND
      calltype IN ('outgoing' , 'incoming')
GROUP BY date(calldate), hour(calldate);
```

Notes:

- I find the hour() function easier to use to get the hour.  However, it returns an integer rather than a time, so it may not be what you really want.
- Using `date()` on `calldate` can prevent the use of an index.  So, I replaced that logic with inequalities.
- I assume you want separate counts for the outgoing and incoming calls.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok ot group by calltype, try:

```
SELECT 
   calltype 
   , calldate
   , from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(calldate)/(60*60))*(60*60)) GroupTime
   ,case when calltype='outgoing' then COUNT(*) else 0 end as CntOut 
   ,case when calltype='ingoing' then COUNT(*) else 0 end as CntIn 
 FROM asterisk.cdr 
 WHERE 
   accountcode = '10102-131' 
   AND DATE (calldate) = DATE (NOW()) 
   AND (calltype = 'outgoing' or calltype='ingoing')--if calltype in only 'ingoing' or 'outgoing', you can omit this line
 GROUP BY calltype, calldate;
```

But if not, the query would be a bit complicated:

```
SELECT 
   t.calldate
   , from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.calldate)/(60*60))*(60*60)) GroupTime
   , t_out.cnt as CntOut
   , t_in.cnt as CntIn
 FROM 
  asterisk.cdr as t
  left join (select calldate,count(*) cnt from asterisk.cdr where calltype='outgoing' group by calldate) as t_out
  on t.calldate=t_out.calldate
  left join (select calldate,count(*) cnt from asterisk.cdr where calltype='ingoing' group by calldate) as t_in
  on t.calldate=t_in.calldate
 WHERE 
   t.accountcode = '10102-131' 
   AND DATE (t.calldate) = DATE (NOW()) 
 GROUP BY  t.calldate;
```

Comment: just getting CntOut

calltype, calldate, GroupTime, CntOut (would also then like the same count for inbound as well for the same groups)

Comment: Do you want the counts in separate columns?